# Are quantum effects also affected by special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

Imagine I've two boxes with 100 radioactive (eg alpha) decay particles with a half life of 10 years. One box stays on Earth and the other is travelling close to speed of light and this box returns to Earth after 10 years. Are the number of decayed particles the same?

Comment: [This](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/muon.html) is a nice example to study.

Comment: Inasmuch as a box of decaying nuclei is nothing but a rudimentary clock, this is just the twin paradox.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I actually think that could be readily expanded into an answer, with just another sentence or two.

Comment: Suppose there is some non-local event going on, could this change the answer?

Comment: @Marijn note that "non-local event" is an oxymoron. An event is, by definition, local.

Answer (score 2):

You ask in the title:

> Are quantum effects also affected by special relativity?

Yes they are.

In the example you propose,

> Are the number of decayed particles the same?

the answer is "no they are not". As an example, I recommend you study this experiment:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment

Comment: But can you compare an atomic clock with the decay of particles by tunneling?

Comment: Atomic clocks basically work on that principle. Particles are 'thrown' back and forward between 2 'mirrors' and the time between every collision with one of the mirrors is monitored. The relative speed of the actual clock  affects particle's path and speed, so it also affects the decay.

Comment: Everything is relative. The decay time will change if you'd be to measure it from Earth (as an example), out of the system. And if you'd be to measure the decay time from the clock's perspective, you'd have the same decay time.
That's why in the above experiment I linked, they used 3 clocks. One stationary on earth so they had a reference to compare them to.

Comment: I have edited your answer so that it is clear for what part you are answering "yes they are". I was confused because I was concentrating to the question in the body , and then I read the title again and the link you gave shows you have answered correctly the title. A qualification was missing .

Comment: What is the cause of a slower emission of particles in the box travelling close to the speed of light?  I understand that time slows down in the travelling box viewed from the earth, but what is "slowing" the decay? Is the entropy increase of the travelling box slowing down?

Comment: @MatteoConta The time dilatation itself is the cause. Atoms require more time to emit radiation and radiation particles require more time to travel the same distance. Viewed from outside the system, everything in that system is slowed down.

I'd suggest to check the Twin Paradox.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that time slows down, but... what is causing the time dilatation ? Time is always measured with the help of another physical entity: the frequency of oscillation in a quartz cristal or the cycles of radiation corresponding to the transition between two energy levels of the caesium-133 atom in atomic clocks. So, what is slowing down this first actors in order to give us a dilation of time?

Comment: @MatteoConta https://www.quora.com/Can-anybody-formulate-the-Lorentz-Transformation-of-the-displayed-time-of-an-atomic-clock-in-Special-Relativity

Answer (score 1):

That actually works with muons produced in the upper atmosphere.
Because of their 2 µs lifetime, very few of them would reach the ground, if they were not traveling at relativistic speeds. In fact, most of them do reach the ground because of the relativistic time dilation.

Comment: The classic result to cite here is that of the Rossi-Hall experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, particle decay is affected by time dilation. You can see this effect in high energy experiments, where the expected decay length of an unstable particle is given by $$l=\gamma v\tau\approx \gamma c\tau $$

That is, higher energy particles take longer to decay because of time dilation. Muons have a lifetime of $2.2\rm\mu s $, but because of this effect, the average muon lifetime in the g-2 experiment at Brookhaven was significantly longer. Similar effects are seen in all high energy physics experiments.